# Generation of 3D terrain with separate quads

Tags: c#, algorithm, 3d, vertex

I am working on code which should generate 3d terrain like this: 
[image: Example]

I've made code before which generates the terrain with shared vertices, but since I want the quads to be textured separately, I'm going to need to have 4 vertices and 6 indices for the triangles in each quad.

I'm using a single-dimensional array for the vertices and one for the indices, but I am having trouble figuring out the algorithm for placing the the vertices at the correct positions and calculating the right indices for the triangles.

Here is some old code where I used shared vertices:

```
for (int x = 0; x < worldData.Width; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < worldData.Height; y++)
            {
                vertices[x + (y * worldData.Width)] = new Vector3(x * TileDiameter, worldData.Elevation[x + (y * worldData.Width)] * HeightUnitValue, y * TileDiameter);
            }

    int t = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < worldData.Width - 1; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < worldData.Height - 1; y++)
        {
            int upperLeft = x + worldData.Width + (y * worldData.Width);
            int upperRight = x + worldData.Width + 1 + (y * worldData.Width);
            int lowerLeft = x + (y * worldData.Width);
            int lowerRight = x + 1 + (y * worldData.Width);

            triangles[t] = upperLeft;
            triangles[t + 1] = upperRight;
            triangles[t + 2] = lowerLeft;
            triangles[t + 3] = lowerLeft;
            triangles[t + 4] = upperRight;
            triangles[t + 5] = lowerRight;
            t += 6;
        }
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why don't you want shared vertices? Is it a choice of style? Without shared vertices you will have hard edges between adjacent quads with different textures. Using [terrain texture blending](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14631076/925580) will probably give much nicer results.

Comment: @Lucius I'm trying to get the kind of terrain as you had in old games such as Transport tycoon [Example](http://abdussamad.com/uploads/ttscreenshot.png)

Comment: You don't really say what's going wrong. If you go through step by step, where does your code produce odd results?

Comment: This question should belong to http://gamedev.stackexchange.com You will probably have a better response, there.